# Class "XSLTProcessor' not found

Tags: php, xml, xls

I'm trying to transform a XML file to a HTML output with XSLT..

My code is as following:

```
<?php

$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('file.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('file.xsl');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor;

$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);

?>
```

But I'm getting the error: Fatal error: Class 'XSLTProcessor' not found

I know this has something to do with the fact dat the xsltprocessor is not compiled with PHP on my server... But I can't seem to find a way to enable it. (I do not control the server, but my hosting does)

Answer (score 6):

Just install : `sudo apt-get install php5-xsl`

**AND RESTART your APACHE Server ;)**

Answer (score 3):

> I do not control the server

The PHP [XSL extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) can *only* be installed and enabled by the sysadmin.

While it's [*compiled* by default](https://www.php.net/manual/en/xsl.installation.php), it is usually not *installed* by default when the server is using a pre-packaged version of PHP.  Ask your host to install the `php-xml` package if you're on a *nix.  If you're hosting on Windows, it becomes a bit more involved, as it requires finding the right .dll file (which may or may not be included in the official distribution) and editing php.ini.

Comment: On Windows, the official MSI installer includes it.

Answer (score 2):

With apache2/php5, you need the php5-xsl extension installed and enabled.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php gives information on how to install the xsl extension. To enable, put the line "extension=php_xsl.so" in your php.ini file.

If it's still not working, create a new .php file on your server containing the line "". Load the file you just created, and search for "xsl" to see if the extension is actually being loaded.

Comment: restart webserver after php5-xsl installation

Answer (score 2):

Its necessary install the XLS extension.

My solution by my context.

I'm using one docker container contain ubuntu base and using php-fpm (ie if you simply already use linux ubuntu in the same).

The steps to install this extension in my context were:

First search xsl extension on linux repository

`sudo apt-cache search xsl`

I ended up finding the php5-xsl, so it was only install

`sudo apt-get install php5-xsl`

that the installation process the setup configuration is already added, if does not happen, just make yourself

`sudo vim /etc/php5/mods-available/xsl.ini`

insert this content:
`extension=xsl.so`

(obviously the paths are according to your php configuration settings, but my example is the default configuration)

Restart you php fpm and done (`sudo service php5-fpm restart`)!

Answer (score 1):

If your php environment is on linux you can probably enable the php extension by using this command:

```
yum install php-xml
```

If it is a windows system, you can go into your php.ini config file and uncomment the php_xml.dll extension.

Hope that helps. A quick google search can answer questions like these in the future btw.