# Fatal error: Class 'XSLTProcessor' not found - but is installed

Tags: php, azure, xslt, php-extension

When try to do the following

```
$xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
```

I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Class 'XSLTProcessor' not found in

I've seen [this question about this exact same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930726/fatal-error-class-xsltprocessor-not-found) (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038262/class-xsltprocessor-not-found)) but I think this is different. Am I right in saying (I've tested it and appear to be) that because the extension details are shown in phpinfo() it is indeed installed correctly?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is that the case, or would it always show in phpinfo() regardless of it being installed successfully? And do you know what might be causing the error if it is successfully installed?

I've tried several versions of PHP and for what it is worth I am hosted on Azure and have [followed and checked the instructions here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime) which further leads me to believe the extension is installed correctly.

Comment: There is also that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962048/php-extension-not-working-on-windows-azure . May you try?

Comment: I did follow those instructions, found some other info that makes me think it is to do with 32-bit system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you enable the `php_xsl` extension on Azure? If you manually upload the DLL library to Azure and config via **Configure via ini settings** section of [How to: Enable extensions in the default PHP runtime](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime). It maybe that the DLL library you configured doesn't match the PHP version or OS version.

However, Azure Web Apps has already contain the `php_xsl.dll` library in the `ext` folder of PHP runtime in every available version. But by default Azure PHP runtime doesn't enable it. you can login Kudu console site of your Azure Web App service, and direct to the default `ext` folder, e.g `D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.0\ext`. You can find all the libraries provided by Azure.

So, please delete your old configurations, and try to follow the **Configure via ini settings** section of [How to: Enable extensions in the default PHP runtime](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime), add the configuration in the `extensions.ini`:

`extension=php_xsl.dll`

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks, it was actually a mismatch been 32 bit and 64 bit. Should have spotted it sooner, but your answer lead me there!